# How to pass an array as an object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm able to pass the values of array  by this way and its working

```
const obj = [
  { text1: "John", text2: "male" },
  { text1: "Philip", text2: "male" },
  { text1: "Matthew", text2: "male" },
  { text1: "Richard", text2: "male" },
 ];
```

But i need to pass it like this

```
var obj = {
    text1: ["John", "Philip", "Matthew", "Richard"],
    text2: ["male", "male", "male", "male"]
};
```

Comment: Do **all** objects in the initial array have **only** `text1` and `text2`, or are there other properties?

Comment: only text 1 and text2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const input = [
  { text1: "John", text2: "male" },
  { text1: "Philip", text2: "male" },
  { text1: "Matthew", text2: "male" },
  { text1: "Richard", text2: "male" },
 ];

const output = {
    text1: input.map( e => e.text1 ),
    text2: input.map( e => e.text2 )
};
```

Comment: is there any way to pass it like an array without repeatedly typing text1 and text2

Comment: @BarryAllen You don't need to repeat anything besides each property name twice (once for the source, once for the destination) - am I missing something?

Comment: No @Dai  , I got your point . Like by any chance is it possible to pass a array into  the component , like this `text1: ["John", "Philip", "Matthew", "Richard"],
    text2: ["male", "male", "male", "male"]` . Two properties with four/many item array.

Comment: @BarryAllen What do you mean by "component"? And the code I posted assumes `input` is your `obj` array, and it will correctly handle arrays of any size.

Comment: Ok @dai.Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to group values by keys

1. Use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop through every item of `input`
2. At each item try to collect all keys' name belong to this item
3. Use `for...loop` on each keys' name and check  if `obj[k]` is empty then we have to assign an empty array and [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) the value by this key(`k`) into `obj[k]`.

This is the solution

```js
    const input = [
      {text1: 'John', text2: 'male'},
      {text1: 'Philip', text2: 'male'},
      {text1: 'Matthew', text2: 'male'},
      {text1: 'Richard', text2: 'male'},
    ];

    function toKeyArray(array) {
      const obj = {};
      array.forEach(item => {
        const keys = Object.keys(item);
        for (const k of keys) {
          (obj[k] = obj[k] || []).push(item[k]);
        }
      });

      return obj;
    }

    const output = toKeyArray(input);
    console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

We can achieve this using `Array.reduce` and `Object.entries`

```js
const obj = [{text1:"John",text2:"male"},{text1:"Philip",text2:"male"},{text1:"Matthew",text2:"male"},{text1:"Richard",text2:"male"},]

const formatData = (data) => data.reduce((res, obj) => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    res[key] = [...(res[key] || []), val];
  });
  return res;
}, {});


console.log(formatData(obj));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.prototype.reduce`, this can be done simply.

```js
const obj = [
  { text1: "John", text2: "male" },
  { text1: "Philip", text2: "male" },
  { text1: "Matthew", text2: "male" },
  { text1: "Richard", text2: "male" },
];

const output = obj.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  Object.keys(cur).forEach((item) => {
    acc[item] ? acc[item].push(cur[item]) : acc[item] = [ cur[item] ];
  });
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = [{
    text1: "John",
    text2: "male"
  },
  {
    text1: "Philip",
    text2: "male"
  },
  {
    text1: "Matthew",
    text2: "male"
  },
  {
    text1: "Richard",
    text2: "male"
  },
];

var output = {}
obj.forEach(item => {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
    if (!output[key]) output[key] = [];
    output[key].push(item[key])
  })
})
console.log(output);
```